# Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() returns null int AndroidTestCase

Tags: android, android-testing

I have a test case, and using there 
`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` call, and it returns null.

I have the "write external storage" permission in app's manifest (and sd cards works fine in app), but it does not work in test case. Why and how to fix it?

Device is SGS3, os version is 4.4.

[image: Debugger]

Comment: it should return the internal sdcard path in 4.4 not null

Comment: @ankitagrawal take a look at updated post, I've uploaded the debugger screenshot.

Comment: did u check if sdcard is null or 2nd line

Answer (score 3):

you have to add the below permission in the Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I've added it, but it does not help.